# Returning the the product of all elements of both diagonals value ( primary and secondary diagonal:(1,5,9) with (7,5,3))of an 2d Array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I have this method to find the result of multiplying the primary and secondary diagonal of a 2d Array

```
public static int produsDiagonle(int[][] coloane) {
        int produsulDiagonalelor = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < coloane.length; row++) {

            produsulDiagonalelor = produsulDiagonalelor + (coloane[row][row] * coloane[row][coloane.length - row - 1]);


        }
        return produsulDiagonalelor;
    }
```

The array is this:

```
int[][] vector2 = {
                {1, 2, 3},
                {4, 5, 6},
                {7, 8, 9}};
```

I have done previously 2 methods to find the sum of the main and the secondary diagonal, which are working as expected (returning 15 for the main one:1,5,6 and 15 for the secondary one: 7,5,3), but for this method, I can not for the life of me return the multiplication value, it seems to add something than multiply something and then add some more, as it returns the value of 91.

Comment: I need to get the result of multiplying (1,5,9) with (7,5,3). I can get the sum of the elements, but I can not get the multiplying result of the elements. E.g 1*5*9*7*5*3=